How to get a list of unverified payment methods in Stripe?
When I get payment methods from Stripe it is showing all verified payment methods.
But I need the payment methods that are not verified so that the user can verify later from the list.
How can I achieve that?
const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
    customer: customerId,
    type: type,
    limit: 100, // Maximum limit per request
    starting_after: startingAfter || undefined,
});


verified isn't a property on the Payment Method object (https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_methods).  Can you describe what you mean by unverified payment methods?  Under what circumstances are they created?

Have you been able to figure this out?
